# how to fix animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c

The animation doesn't work in my main work, it will however work in a new xcode project...

```
[self.buttonHintdisabled setBackgroundImage: [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"c.png" duration:4.0] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

I've set an outlet and I've added this line of code in `viewDidLoad`
And still nothing happens... It's a series of 14 images and they animate across each other.
Each photo is named like this `c0.png`, `c1.png`, `c2.png`, `c3.png` and so on!

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`animatedImageNamed:duration` accepts the first parameter as `NSString` that is a a full path or partial path to file.

For example, if you have c0.png, c1.png, c2.png and so forth, you would do:

```
[UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"c" duration:4.0];
```

***Without*** the suffix and extension.

Comment: Very good, I spent 3.5 hours trying to figure this out.... at least thats imprinted in my mind!

Comment: @Jelter Not a problem; we all experience the same every once in a while. Have fun with it.

Comment: how would I disable this animation when the button is pressed - Ive asked this question in my new post!!!